# How to redirect to other page after .pdf exported in Primefaces?

Tags: java, jsf, primefaces

I want to archive a "Close and Print" function, where after closing the invoice it will be exported right away as .pdf (this is the "print" in the system) and the user will be redirected to the invoice list.

This is the command button I tried to create:

```
<p:menuitem oncomplete="javascript:saved=true" 
            action="#{myController.setFinalAndPrint}"  
            disabled="#{myController.selected.status == 2}"
            value="#{bundle.Finalize} &amp; #{bundle.Print}" 
            update=":center,:growl" 
            icon="ui-icon-check"
            ajax="false"
            class=""/>
```

This is the setFinalAndPrint method in my controller:

```
  public void setFinalAndPrint() {
        setFinal();

        breadCrumb.goToInvoice();

        reportForm();
    }
```

setFinal is working fine, reportForm is also working fine, Chrome is getting the popup to save the .pdf but the page isn't redirected...

Is it possible to export a .pdf and navigate somehow to other page?

Thank you!

EDIT.:

Tried with:

```
oncomplete="location.reload( true );"
```

sadly this doesn't work as well :(

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Found out myself:

use WidgetVar on the button and use jQuery like this:

```
<script type="text/javascript">
    jQuery(document).ready(function(){ 
        PF('myWidgetVar').jq.click();
    }) 
</script>
```